# The project does not work with servlet 4.0 and jsf 2.3

Tags: java, jsf, servlet-4

I have a small Java EE project using CDI, JSF, BeanValidation, Servlet-api in the intellij IDEA. My server is a glassfish 5.0.0, i read that it implements servlet 4.0, cdi 2.0, jsf 2.3 and bean validation 2.0.

I have the following xml configurations:

1.web.xml:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
                 version="3.1">
    <!--Configurations-->
        </web-app>
```

2.faces-config.xml:

```
    <faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

3.beans.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

Now everything is fine, but when i try to change servlet 3.1 to servlet 4.0, jsf 2.2 to jsf 2.3, all jsf pages where i use expression language don't working, for example `<h:commandButton action='#{bean.doSomething}' />` don't fire events

What i'm doing wrong? Sorry for my english.

UPDATE.

I'm moving my project to maven, re-updated all the libraries and everything worked fine, so i think that the problem was in bad configurations or libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, this issue is most likely caused by a know [bug in Mojarra](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4264). After updating the default 2.3.2 javax.faces.jar to at least 2.3.3 in Glassfish 5, JSF will work again as expected.