# Listener on fileUpload no longer triggered after Jetty upgrade

Tags: primefaces, jetty

In our code we use a fileUpload component of Primefaces which was working fine. After upgrading Jetty it stopped working. The component remained untouched during the Jetty upgrade.

```xml
<p:outputPanel id="fileImport" class="file-import">
            <h:outputText id="import-text" style="display:block;" styleClass="bold" value="#{guiMsgBundle['importDialog.file']}" />
            <h:form id="import-form" style="display: block;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:fileUpload id="importFileButton" 
                    widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.dialogWidgetVar}-importFileWidgetVar" 
                    label="#{guiMsgBundle['importDialog.choose']}"
                    mode="advanced" 
                    skinSimple="true" 
                    fileLimit="2" 
                    listener="#{cc.attrs.controller[controllerFct]}"
                    update="#{cc.attrs.updateDown} :#{cc.bindingsMap['script'].clientId}"
                    oncomplete="nextDialog()"
                    allowTypes="#{allowTypes}" />
            </h:form>
            <div class="buttons">
                <p:commandButton id="importCancel" class="secondary-button import-cancel" value="#{guiMsgBundle['dialogActions.cancel']}"
                    oncomplete="PF('#{cc.attrs.dialogWidgetVar}').hide();" update="@none" partialSubmit="true" process="@none" />
            </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

When using Jetty 9.4.42.v20210604 this worked fine.
After upgrading to Jetty 10.0.7 the listener on the fileUpload stopped being called. The nextDialog() on the oncomplete still gets called when the upload button was clicked. The issue is not with the controller function itself as it does not get reached in the first place. For testing purposes it was replaced with a simple JavaScript function which only logged a test message to the console but it was never called.

We are using Primefaces 8.0.7

There are no error messages produced. Neither in the browser console nor in the jetty logs.

The goal is to have the listener be triggered again when the upload button is pressed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Upgrading Primefaces to 10.0.8 made no difference.

Comment: Did you also upgrade Primefaces to one that supports Servlet 4.0? (aka Jakarta EE 8)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55013314/775715 (didn't upgrade your dependencies on primefaces / mojarra / etc)

Comment: Upgrading to Primefaces 10.0.8 made no difference

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

We were missing a multipart-config in the WEB-INF/web.xml.

```
<multipart-config>
    <location/>
    <max-file-size>2147483646</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>2147483646</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>2147483647</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```